# Guaranteeing uniqueness of a string, irrespective of its characters position when generating LtHash-like sum

Tags: php

I'm trying to accomplish what [LtHash](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/227.pdf) offers as functionality, leaving the secure concept alone: compute a sum from a list of items, irrespective of their order to then hash it and use it as an identity of the list. In other words, I'm trying to compare whether or not new items have been added to the list from the past or not.

My input is:`['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']` and my output is:`1347`.

The code below unpacks each item in my array into bytes and simply computes that sum:

```
$sum = 0;

foreach( $collection as $item ) {
    $bytes = unpack( 'C*', $item );

    $sum += array_sum( $bytes );
}
```

But this has a problem. Assume I had `temI1` instead of `Item1`. This is definitely not the same item, but it certainly does contain the same characters (and therefore the same bytes sum), if I were to change my collection to integrate this change, my sum would still be `1347`.

How can I avoid this issue when computing the said sum?

I tried going through each byte, of each string, to subtract the next one from the previous:

```
foreach( $collection as $item ) {
    $bytes = unpack( 'C*', $item );

    //Go through each byte from the string.
    for( $i = 1; $i <= count( $bytes ); $i++ ) {
        //If a next byte exists.
        if( isset( $bytes[$i+1] ) ) {

            $sum += $bytes[$i] - $bytes[$i+1];
        //If not, subtract the last, lone byte from the entire sum.
        } else {
            $sum += $sum - $bytes[$i];
        }
    }
```

But this yields completely wrong results, I just put this up to showcase what my problem is. What can I do to guarantee uniqueness of strings, as well as members in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! Something about this site's interface that turns critical thinking on like a switch...

```
$sum = 0;

foreach( $collection as $item ) {
    $bytes = unpack( 'C*', $item );

    for( $i = 1; $i <= count( $bytes ); $i++ ) {
        if( isset( $bytes[$i+1] ) ) {
            $sum += $bytes[$i] - $bytes[$i+1];
        } else {
            $sum -= $bytes[$i];
        }
    }

}
```

When it dealt with the last, lone byte of each string, it would add to the sum, the `sum - lone_byte`. This code instead just subtracts the last lone byte of each string from the entire sum. Now all requirements are met.